# Create control dynamically for each row C#

Tags: c#, mysql

**problem**

I'm trying to create a control for each row that contains an image.

```
private void ass_wijzig_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //query's
    string count = "select COUNT(Image) from product";
    string query = "select image from product";
    //commands
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(count, connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    int totalcount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= totalcount; i++)
        {
            //What do I need to put here?
        }
    }
```

**Case**

The program looks how many rows there are in my product table. Each created row contains an image. I want the program to check how many rows there are(works) and then create a picturebox which contains the image from the row. As you can see I've already made sure that each row gets counted. I've been told NOT to work with array's. And to retrieve a picture from the database you'll need to work with data adapters and data tables.

**Question**

How can I create a picturebox containing the right image for each row there is in my table?

**Attachment**

*code to put one image in a picturebox*

```
private void ass_wijzig_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string query = "Select Image From Product where productid = 1";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        // MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Image");
        int count = ds.Tables["Image"].Rows.Count;



        if (count > 0)
        {
            var data = (Byte[])(ds.Tables["Image"].Rows[count - 1]["Image"]);
            var stream = new MemoryStream(data);
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
        }
```

***Very Important!, upper code was only used to make sure I was able to put an image in a picturebox, I've included this code to underpin my statement that I had to use data tables and data adapters. This code is not included in my project anymore.***

Thanks in advance

Comment: loop the datatable to get the data one by one and add where it require..

Comment: for each rowindex = 0  to ds.Tables["Image"].Rows.count -1  var data = (Byte[])(ds.Tables["Image"].Rows[rowindex]["Image"]); next  this is vb.net code you can get the value of each row by looping  through the datatable

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian, thanks for your answer, yes I know, but I'm told to use a reader to get my information out of the database. For as far as i know, i need to use data tables and data adapters to retrieve the picture, but a reader and those two wont work together.

Comment: instead of using for each then use for i= 0 to count-1 value

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian could you explain some more please, maybe a little example if it doesn't take much from your time ofcourse

Comment: see vigneshkumar's answer, he has the same point of answer of mine..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
private void ass_wijzig_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
            string query = "Select Image From Product where productid = 1";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            // MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            var ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "Image");
            int count = ds.Tables["Image"].Rows.Count;
           List<PictureBox> pbList = new List<PictureBox>();

            for (int i = 0; i < count-1; i++)
            {                
                var data = (Byte[])(ds.Tables["Image"].Rows[i]["Image"]);
                var stream = new MemoryStream(data);
                pbList[i] = new PictureBox();               
                pbList[i].Name = "pic" + i;
                pbList[i].Size = new Size(300, 75);
                pbList[i].Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
                myform.Controls.Add(pbList[i]);
            } 
      }
```

**Update**

You don't need to loop a array for PictureBox

```
private void ass_wijzig_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
                string query = "Select Image From Product where productid = 1";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                // MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                var ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "Image");
                int count = ds.Tables["Image"].Rows.Count;

                for (int i = 0; i < count-1; i++)
                {                
                    var data = (Byte[])(ds.Tables["Image"].Rows[i]["Image"]);
                    var stream = new MemoryStream(data);
                    PictureBox pbList = new PictureBox();               
                    pbList.Name = "pic" + i;
                    pbList.Size = new Size(300, 75);
                    pbList.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
                    myform.Controls.Add(pbList);
                } 
          }
```

Comment: Yes, I didn't get the downvote either... however, i'm going to try this code right away, thanks for the reply

Comment: The downvote was before your edit. The `for` loop was incorrect. Also, what happens if he happens to have more than `50` products/pictures which is a likely scenario?

Comment: @dtsg this is sample solution. He could change the size as he need. Now i changed Picture box size depend on Row Count

Comment: @VigneshKumar It is still incorrect, shouldn't it be `new PictureBox[count - 1];`?. The OP explicitly stated that he was told to avoid arrays - `I've been told NOT to work with array's.` What's wrong with a `List<PictureBox>`?

Comment: @dtsg  I was aware of the that situation , although thanks for the concern :), I can happily say that this sample works like a charm , the only thing left is to order the pictureboxes underneath eachother. Thank you very much Vignesh Kumar

Comment: @dtsg You cant use `new PictureBox[count - 1];?` and also updated my answer with `List`

Comment: @dtsg Is a List<PictureBox> a better solution then?, I would like to hear more, the more I learn the better it is :)

Comment: as you (@user3697100) said you no need array, he (vignesh) has used list controls..!!

Comment: @user3697100 Yes a `List<PictureBox>` would be a better idea as you don't have to worry about resizing or the initial size of the collection. Adding and removing is a lot easier too. And as you said yourself, you were told to stay away from arrays..

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian Yes, thats true, when I used array's in this code i was getting errors thrown at me, somebody told me I was better off using a simple reader so thats why I said that, now this is different. The important part is that the code works, I've updated it with the new code from vignesh. It still works very well and without arrays. :)

Comment: @VigneshKumar Why do you need an array? You are adding the control directly to the forms `Controls` collection inside of your loop. It's pointless...

Comment: @DGibbs Why would it be pointless, it adds a new picturebox for every row, thats what I've asked for

Comment: @JumpingJack My point is that you do not need a `pics[]` or `pbList` to store the picture boxes simply because he is adding each new `PictureBox` directly to the forms `Controls` collection. It's entirely unnecessary

Comment: @DGibbs Yes i agree with you. Ill update my solution

Comment: @DGibbs What would be a better solution then?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void ass_wijzig_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string query = "Select Image From Product where productid = 1";

       MySqlDataAdapter adpt=new MySqlDataAdapter(query,connection);
       DataTable dt=new DataTable();
       adpt.Fill(dt);
     if(dt.Rows.Count>0)
     {
      PictureBox pcb[]=new PictureBox[dt.rows.count];
       for(int i=0;i<dt.Rows.Count;i++)
       {
            var data = (Byte[])(dt.Rows[i]["Image"].ToString());
            var stream = new MemoryStream(data);
            pcb[i].Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
       }

     }
}
```